# How to Copy HTML file along with all the associated images and scripts folder?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, file-copying

I want to copy an HTML file from one location to another using VB.net.
When i use any of the  three FileCopy, System.IO.File.Copy, My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile
it copies only the file and not the "filename_files" folder which contain its associated images and scripts.

What i want to do programatically is copy a.html to another location as b.html

when i do that and open b.html it opens it without any images and scripts.

Pls help

Comment: That'll require to copy each file manually from source location to target location, and before you start copying files located within folder at source location, you'll need to create folder with the same name at target location, than begin copying of the files.

Comment: but that also means that i have to change the content of HTML files as it has src tag and the path is of "oldfilename_files" folder. How to do that?

Comment: You'll not have to change content of html files as long as folder name you'll be creating at target location is same as that of source location, keeping in mind that you've given relative paths in `src` instead of absolute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following two methods that collectively can copy folder that that includes scripts and images thus, with built-in method `FileCopy` copy your HTML file, and using below methods, copy your required folder.

I found the first method that returns an array of files in a given path at [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.Asp?ID=41)

```
Public Function FileList(Mask As String) As String()

    Dim sWkg As String
    Dim sAns() As String
    Dim lCtr As Long

    ReDim sAns(0) As String
    sWkg = Dir(Mask, vbNormal)

    Do While Len(sWkg)

        If sAns(0) = "" Then
            sAns(0) = sWkg
        Else
            lCtr = UBound(sAns) + 1
            ReDim Preserve sAns(lCtr) As String
            sAns(lCtr) = sWkg
        End If
        sWkg = Dir
   Loop
   FileList = sAns
End Function
```

Now using the above method, and the below method, you can copy folder by specifying Source and Target paths. The method will return boolean value specifying whether folder was copied or not.

```
Public Function FolderCopy(ByVal SourceFolder As String, ByVal TargetFolder As String) As Boolean
    Dim flist() As String
    Dim sURL As String = New String(SourceFolder)
    Dim tURL As String = New String(TargetFolder)
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim slashpos As Long
    If Not Directory.Exists(tURL) Then

        slashpos = InStrRev(sURL, "\") 'Get position of last occurrence if '\' in given path
        If slashpos <> sURL.Length Then 'Check if URL does not have slash at its end
            sURL = sURL & "\" 'Add slash at URL end
        End If

        flist = FileList(sURL)
        slashpos = InStrRev(tURL, "\") 'Get position of last occurrence if '\' in given path
        If slashpos = tURL.Length Then
            tURL = tURL.Substring(0, tURL.Length - 1)
        End If
        slashpos = InStrRev(tURL, "\")

        Try
            Directory.CreateDirectory(tURL)
            For i = 0 To flist.Length - 1
                FileCopy(sURL & flist(i), tURL & "\" & flist(i))
            Next
            FolderCopy = True
        Catch ex As Exception
            FolderCopy = False
        End Try

    Else
        FolderCopy = False
    End If
End Function
```

Make sure that you include `Imports System.IO` at the beginning of the class before using `FolderCopy` method, and note that both these methods are required to be included.

Answer (score 0):

```
' copy all files and subdirectories from the
' specified source to the specified destination.
Private Sub RecursiveCopyFiles( ByVal sourceDir As String, ByVal destDir As String, _
ByVal fRecursive As Boolean)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim posSep As Integer
    Dim sDir As String
    Dim aDirs() As String
    Dim sFile As String
    Dim aFiles() As String

    ' Add trailing separators to the supplied paths if they don't exist.
    If Not sourceDir.EndsWith(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()) Then 
         sourceDir &= System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
    End If

    If Not destDir.EndsWith(System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar.ToString()) Then
         destDir &= System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar
    End If

    ' Recursive switch to continue drilling down into dir structure.
    If fRecursive Then
        ' Get a list of directories from the current parent.
        aDirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir)

        For i = 0 To aDirs.GetUpperBound(0)
            ' Get the position of the last separator in the current path.
            posSep = aDirs(i).LastIndexOf("\")

            ' Get the path of the source directory.
            sDir = aDirs(i).Substring((posSep + 1), aDirs(i).Length -(posSep + 1))

            ' Create the new directory in the destination directory.
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir + sDir)

            ' Since we are in recursive mode, copy the children also
            RecursiveCopyFiles(aDirs(i), (destDir + sDir), fRecursive)
        Next
    End If

    ' Get the files from the current parent.
    aFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir)

    ' Copy all files.
    For i = 0 To aFiles.GetUpperBound(0)
        ' Get the position of the trailing separator.
        posSep = aFiles(i).LastIndexOf("\")

        ' Get the full path of the source file.
        sFile = aFiles(i).Substring((posSep + 1), aFiles(i).Length - (posSep+ 1))

        ' Copy the file.
        System.IO.File.Copy(aFiles(i), destDir + sFile)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: it's recursive function so understand recursion first